# Not able to restore transaction logs in STANDBY mode in SQL server 2017

Tags: sql-server, logging, mode, standby

We have a client who has been providing us with full database backup of sql server 2016 database everyday.
We asked them to send only one initial copy of full backup followed by transaction logs(one in every 30 minutes) so that we can have more recent data.
On our side, we are using SQL Server 2017 version. We are able to restore the full backup and all subsequent T-logs only in NORECOVERY mode. But we need the database to be in STANDBY mode, so that we can do T-Log restore and also read data from the database. We cannot wait till all the T-logs restore finishes because there is no end to the T-log files, they keep on coming.
The issue is we are not able to move the database into STANDBY mode. We are able to put it in either Restoration or RECOVERY modes only.
I found from Microsoft doc. that STANDBY mode is supported only between same version of SQL Servers. Is there anyway of reading the data from Restoring database while restoring logs.

Comment: Nope, if you want to do do this with log shipping (or ghetto log shipping) you will need to be on the same SQL version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway of reading the data from Restoring database while restoring logs [on a higher SQL Server version].

No. The database must be upgraded before it can be read, and that happens after recovery.

You can always install an additional SQL 2016 instance on the server with version downgrade rights.